# Check weather the path is directory or file in Shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to find out the array items are file path or directory path.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=("/var/log/symantec/sgs-td","/var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log","/var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log", "/var/log/sa")

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
if [[ -d $i ]]; then
    echo "$i is a directory"
elif [[ -f $i ]]; then
    echo "$i is a file"
else
    echo "$i is not valid"
    exit 1
fi
done
```

I am do not have knowledge of shell syntax.

If the path is directory then print ..is a directory or if file then print its a file.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's the actual output you get when running the script?

Comment: /var/log/symantec/sgs-td,/var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log,/var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log, is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big small mistake was I put comma in array list while declaring. Rest Code has no problem and it works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=("/char/vlog/tec/sg" "/chr/lib/mysql/mysq.log" "/dar/lib/mysql/error.log" "/char/log/sua")

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
if [[ -d $i ]]; then
    echo "$i is a directory"
elif [[ -f $i ]]; then
    echo "$i is a file"
else
    echo "$i is not valid"
    exit 1
fi
done
```